# What is the nextSequenceToken for the PutLogEvents API for AWS.CloudWatchLogs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

What is the `nextSequenceToken` mentioned here?

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/API_PutLogEvents.html

Unclear to me, and probably others.

Comment: So do you still have questions?

Comment: thanks sorry I didn't see this answer until just now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**This question (and answer) are obsolete**

I'm leaving the answer here, because it was relevant in 2019 when the question was asked. See @ErmiyaEskandary answer below for more information.

---

Each batch of events sent to CloudWatch Logs must include a sequence token (from the [PutLogEvents API doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/API_PutLogEvents.html)):

```
{
   "logEvents": [ 
      { 
         "message": "string",
         "timestamp": number
      }
   ],
   "logGroupName": "string",
   "logStreamName": "string",
   "sequenceToken": "string"
}
```

The response returns `nextSequenceToken` (again from the API docs):

```
{
   "nextSequenceToken": "string",
   "rejectedLogEventsInfo": { 
      "expiredLogEventEndIndex": number,
      "tooNewLogEventStartIndex": number,
      "tooOldLogEventEndIndex": number
   }
}
```

So the short answer to your question is: If you have a single producer writing to a stream, you can save `nextSequenceToken` and use it to populate `sequenceToken` for your next `PutLogEvents` request.

The longer answer is that you *can't* use this technique if you have multiple producers, because a producer doesn't have access to the response to another producer's request. Instead, you must call [DescribeLogStreams](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeLogStreams.html) before each request. The following code is extracted from a Java logging framework [that I wrote](https://github.com/kdgregory/log4j-aws-appenders/blob/master/aws-shared/src/main/java/com/kdgregory/logging/aws/cloudwatch/CloudWatchLogWriter.java) (so includes references to functions that aren't shown here, and may contain syntax errors because I elided stuff specific to the logging library):

```
/**
 *  This function retrieves the current information for a specific log stream.
 *  DescribeLogStreams is a paginated operation, which means that we have to
 *  be prepared for a large number of rows in the response, but since we're
 *  passing the full stream name as a prefix this should never happen.
 */
private LogStream findLogStream(String logGroupName, String logStreamName)
{
    DescribeLogStreamsRequest request = new DescribeLogStreamsRequest()
                                        .withLogGroupName(logGroupName)
                                        .withLogStreamNamePrefix(logStreamName);
    DescribeLogStreamsResult result;
    do
    {
        result = client.describeLogStreams(request);
        for (LogStream stream : result.getLogStreams())
        {
            if (stream.getLogStreamName().equals(logStreamName))
                return stream;
        }
        request.setNextToken(result.getNextToken());
    } while (result.getNextToken() != null);
    return null;
}

/**
 *  This function tries to send a batch of messages, retrieving the sequence
 *  number for each batch and handling the data race if another process has
 *  made that sequence number invalid.
 */
private List<LogMessage> attemptToSend(List<LogMessage> batch)
{
    if (batch.isEmpty())
        return batch;

    PutLogEventsRequest request = new PutLogEventsRequest()
                                  .withLogGroupName(config.logGroupName)
                                  .withLogStreamName(config.logStreamName)
                                  .withLogEvents(constructLogEvents(batch));

    for (int ii = 0 ; ii < 5 ; ii++)
    {
        LogStream stream = findLogStream();

        try
        {
            request.setSequenceToken(stream.getUploadSequenceToken());
            client.putLogEvents(request);
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }
        catch (InvalidSequenceTokenException ex)
        {
            stats.updateWriterRaceRetries();
            Utils.sleepQuietly(100);
            // continue retry loop
        }
        catch (DataAlreadyAcceptedException ex)
        {
            reportError("received DataAlreadyAcceptedException, dropping batch", ex);
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            reportError("failed to send batch", ex);
            return batch;
        }
    }

    reportError("received repeated InvalidSequenceTokenException responses -- increase batch delay?", null);
    stats.updateUnrecoveredWriterRaceRetries();
    return batch;
}
```

Most of the exceptions that you'll get back from the `PutLogEvents` request are unrecoverable, so this code ignores them. `InvalidSequenceTokenException`, however, indicates that there was a race between two producers, and another producer was able to write a batch between the time that this producer retrieved the stream description and tried to write its batch. This is unlikely but possible, so it makes a few retries and then rejects the batch (it's requeued for another attempt).

There's one last piece of the response that *may* be important to you: CloudWatch has rules about the timestamps on events in a batch (not too far in the past or future). If your batch contains events that are outside of that range, they will be dropped but the rest of the events will be added to the stream. You can see if this happens by looking at the `rejectedLogEventsInfo` object in the response, which will have non-zero indexes if any records were dropped (for the logging framework, that's not likely to happen, and there's no correcting for it, so I just ignore that response value).

Comment: nice answer ty...so I guess the fastest way to get the next token is some mutex, get a lock, request the next token, write to the logs, then release lock...but maybe there is a faster way

Comment: @AlexanderMills - I don't think a mutex is the right way to go. Assuming that you have multiple threads that want to write messages (much like a logging framework consumer), I think that the best approach is to have a background thread that sends them, with a message queue in-between. If you have a lot of independent writers, you'll run into the [5 requests/second limit](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/cloudwatch_limits_cwl.html).

Comment: Yeah that approach seems better, appreciate that

Comment: What's the point of asking for such a token? Why does the API require us to send it?

Comment: @A.Sallai - the only people who can answer that question are the original developers of the API. I'm not one of them, but I suspect that it's a leaked implementation detail.

Answer (score 2):

As of 4th January 2023, the `SequenceToken` field is now deprecated & ignored by the API. It seems to have always been a case of a leaky abstraction, that should've never been there in the first place.

**You do not need to specify or use the sequence token anymore.**

It is still returned and accepted by the API for backwards compatibility, but I would recommend to refactor and remove it from any existing code for simpler logic.

As per [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/API_PutLogEvents.html#CWL-PutLogEvents-request-sequenceToken) & [announcement](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2023/01/amazon-cloudwatch-logs-log-stream-transaction-quota-sequencetoken-requirement/):

> Amazon CloudWatch Logs is also *removing the requirement of providing a sequence token* when calling Amazon CloudWatch Logs PutLogEvents API.
>
> CloudWatch Logs will *still accept PutLogEvents API request with sequence token* and *return a PutLogEvents API response with a sequence token* to maintain backwards compatibility. Your PutLogEvents API calls will be accepted, and *CloudWatch Logs won't return InvalidSequenceToken errors* irrespective of providing an invalid sequence token.